# Java StringWriter StringBuilder exception at toString

Tags: java, android, tostring, stringbuilder, stringwriter

Ok.. this is totally weird. I'm trying to make a http request in android. It works and I can 'build' a string using StringWriter but the code throws an exception at writer.toString(). It makes no difference if I use StringBuilder or StringWriter.

```
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    StringBuilder writer = new StringBuilder();
    //StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    int ch;
    while(( ch = is.read()) != -1) { 
        writer.append((char)ch);
    }
    String theString = writer.toString();
    return theString;
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    return e.getMessage();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please add the stacktrace?

Comment: +1 for micha's comment, Java should not crash, but throw an exception instead

Comment: That's also strange. When debugging step by step it goes to the line return e.getMessage(), but here it says "e cannot be resolved to a vaiable". So is there another way to get a stack trace in eclipse??

Comment: @user568021 looks like your debugger might not be in sync with the running code, make sure the apk being debugged is the code currently shown in the IDE. Also, you could do a simple e.printStackTrace(); in the catch block.

Comment: This will sound a little newby: Do you guys ever run to an exception where eclipse debugger takes you nowhere and is says "Source not found" in red color?

Comment: e.printStackTrace() should put it in your console

Comment: not really, it will print the complete stack trace where the exception it is called on occured.

Comment: "Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.nw.testapp' on port 8613" is the last line in "console". Even if I add printStackTrace

Comment: So why doesn't it print the stack trace?

Comment: Why not remove the 'catch' block, run the code and then the exception will be presented to you?

Comment: If I remove the catch block I can't compile the code... unhandled exception.

Comment: Terminology please. You got an *exception,* not a 'crash'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your HTTP thread is attempting to update the UI Thread with the `HTTPResponse` in a `TextView` or other such UI element so a `CalledFromWrongThreadException` is being raised.

Using a `Handler` or other such mechanism to redirect to the UI Thread for the UI update will solve your problem.

Comment: Nope. I can see in the debug perspective: the values are added to writer.

Comment: There are many ways to display LogCat, which is in the DDMS window when you are debugging. One way is in the Console. There is a toolbar icon called "Display Selected Console" in which you can switch between  "Android", "DDMS", and others. There is also a DDMS "Perspective". Copy and Paste to this forum. Please read ALL advice. "e.printStackTrace()" is your friend.

Comment: If your device is debugging, then DDMS is connected. If the DDMS console is empty, it may be connected to a different device or emulator. You can switch which device goes to DDMS in the DDMS "Perspective".

Comment: Yes, that is your LogCat at the PasteBin link you posted. It tells us that your app is throwing a `CalledFromWrongThreadException`. So, it is not crashing on writer.toString() at all. It is crashing because a non-UI thread is attempting to update the UI, probably with the result of your HTTP call. The fix is to use a Handler to send the data to the UI thread and update it asynchronously. Sounds complicated, but it is easy. Search for "Handler" examples. There are many ways to execute something on the UI thread. Handler is just one of them.

Comment: But if I comment out the line where I set the TextView value it still crashes. And step by step debugging obviously shows that code crashes on writer.toString() and than it goes to the catch clause.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26982/discussion-between-user568021-and-david-manpearl)

Comment: One more question: do you have any idea why was the debugger "tricking me"?

Comment: Yes. It was out of sync. It was working off a slightly different symbol table than the actual code base installed on your device, so the line of code of the crash was off by an offset.